# sharepoint branding ms-main question

Tags: 2007

I have written my own custom CSS

how do i control image  header.jpg depending on the screen resolution . It gets skewed for different resolutions ..

Thanks

/* display our custom header background */
.ms-main { 
    background: white url('Header.jpg') no-repeat left top;
}

/* make the top bar and the bar behind nav transparent */
.ms-globalbreadcrumb, .ms-globalTitleArea, .ms-bannerContainer { 
    background-image: none !important; 
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

/* increas the hiehgt of the header area */
.ms-globalTitleArea { 
    height: 100px; 
}

/* hide the site title and site icon */
td.ms-titleimagearea img, .ms-sitetitle h1.ms-sitetitle { 
    display: none; 
}

/* hide the bottom border on the top bar */
td.ms-globalbreadcrumb { 
    border:0px transparent none !important; 
}

/* advanced search color */
.ms-globalTitleArea .ms-sblink a:link, .ms-globalTitleArea .ms-sblink a:visited, .ms-globalTitleArea a:hover { 
    color: white; 
}

/* fix for firefox top bar */
td.ms-globallinks { 
    white-space:nowrap; 
}

http://picasaweb.google.com/103330992872334209006/UntitledAlbum#5514926743118804882

high resolution pic I can see the whole picture(1280 X 800) 
low resolution pic I can just part of the picture ( 600 X 800)
if you can help with this that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can show me with a screen shot what you are trying to do, I can help.

Comment: http://picasaweb.google.com/103330992872334209006/UntitledAlbum#5514926743118804882

Comment: Try this for starters

.ms-main { background:#012BA4 url('Header.jpg') no-repeat right top; }

If this changes any other colours such as the main body, set that to  #ffffff.